# Dual Screen misery, unable to install nvidia without crashing unity and turning machine into brick

Tags: nvidia, ati, multimedia

I am currently on Ubuntu 12.10 and have tried and FAILED to install a graphics card to run a dual screen. I am currently running the following graphics card, Intel Mobile Series 4. The machine is a Dell.  It's also a 32 bit machine.

I have tried everything to get nvidia (or any other graphics card AMD) on this machine, but to no avail.

Everytime I follow some of the advice, unity shuts down and turns the computer into a brick - and I have to re-install Ubuntu from scratch.

The following was the latest example I followed, http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/

I am disappointed with Ubuntu for not pre-installing these drives in the first place. Wasted time in my opinion, trying to get a dual screen working.

What I need to know?

- Am i better off upgrading to 13.04?
- Is the Intel Graphics processor not going to work with nvidia?

Is there anyone out there who resolved this situation with a machine with similar spec? I am begging Ubuntu to sort this out. My time could be better spent learning command line, and doing more productive things. Any help would be gratefully accepted.

UPDATE:

I folowed the advice of nvidia installation was taken from here, http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/

This part is fine

| sudo su
| apt-get update
| apt-get install linux-headers-generic
| apt-get dist-upgrade
| reboot

The part where it goes wrong...

| sudo su
| apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
| nvidia-xconfig
| reboot

Once this has been done and I reboot, there is just brick - no unity just login into truncated home screen with black colouring at the side.

Is there a potential conflict between Intel grpahics cards and nvidia drives.  I also must stree that the method set out by Mr Falkfinge is for 64-bit machine, I am running a 32-bit.

Again any help would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate your discrete card in the BIOS ? Some computer require this before installing the driver.

Although not exactly related to your question about nvidia driver I will answer to this one

```
Am i better off upgrading to 13.04?
```

The answer is yes. And right after upgrading to 13.04 you should immediately upgrade to 13.10, Ubuntu 12.10 will be supported until april 2014 but 13.04 until january. If you want your machine to be upgradable up to 14.04 that's what I would do.

ref : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_timeline